# ERROR: The ID value "xxxxxxxxxxxx" occurs twice in the same BY group. when transposing a complex dataset

Tags: sas

I have a strange data set and I am hoping you all can help me. I have a data set of the levels of certain environmental contaminants which are measured multiple ways along with the limit of detection are present in a group of research participants. I need these in a wide format, but unfortunately they are currently long and the naming conventions don’t easily translate.

This is what it looks like now:

```
ID   Class      Name    Weight Amount_lipids Amount_plasma LOD 


1   AAA Lead    1.55    44.0         10.0      5.00
1   AAB Mercury 1.55    222.0        100.0     75.00
2   AAA Lead    1.25    25.5         12.0      5.00
```

I have tried various forms of Proc Transpose with no luck and this seems to be more complex than what specifying a prefix can handle.

I want it to look like this:

```
ID Weight Lead_lip Lead_plas Lead_LOD Mercury_lip Mercury_plas Mercury_LOD
1  1.55   44.0     10.0       5.0     222.0   100.0        75.0
2  1.25   25.5     12.0       5.0     .           .        .
```

I tried a two step transpose process but received the following error ERROR: The ID value "xxxxxxxxxxxx" occurs twice in the same BY group

```
  by id weight name;
run;

proc transpose data=want_intermediate out=want;
  by id weight;
  id name _name_;
run;
```

Comment: Possibly answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033305/proc-transpose-with-duplicate-id-values

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a record with the same ID and weight so it's duplicated. 
You can add a counter for each ID record and use that. This is a double wide transpose, and it looks like your code was cut off. So to add an enumerator for each ID:

```
data temp;
    set have;
    by id;
    if first.id then count=1;
    else count+1;
run;
```

Then modify your PROC TRANSPOSE to use ID and count in the BY statement.